# Calling React function from stencil web component

Tags: reactjs, stenciljs

This is my react functional component

```
const goTo = () => {
    console.log("This method call.");
  };
return (
    <div>
      <div className="container">
        <otp-web-component
        callBack={() => goTo}>
        </otp-web-component>
      </div>
    </div>  
)
```

This is stencil component

```
    @Component({
      tag: "otp-web-component",
      styleUrl: "my-component.css",
    })
    export class otpcomponent {
    @Method() CallBack:()=>void; //calling this on button click
    
       @Listen("event.keydown.enter")
      goBack() {
   //  calling callback function here
       }
        render(){
          return(
           <button
              class="btn btn-primary"
              style={buttonStyle}
              onClick={this.goBack.bind(this)}
              >
               get
             </button>
          )
        }
```

When clicking on get button in stencil component it should execute the react function goTo();

Answer (score 0):

Just listing some things that look wrong and might help you figure out what the problem is:

1. You're using the `@Method` decorator for `CallBack` but you're not defining a method. You probably want to use the `@Prop` decorator. It's possible to pass a function (or any JS object) as a prop. You can read about the method decorator here: https://stenciljs.com/docs/methods.
2. When using your component in React, you're not actually calling the `goTo` function. You're passing a function that returns the `goTo` function instead because you forgot the `()`. You either want to use `callBack={goTo}` or `callBack={() => goTo()}`.
3. You've defined your prop (the one with the `@Method` decorator) as `CallBack` (pascal case) but then you're using it as `callBack` (camel case). Stencil component property names are not case insensitive.
4. `@Listen("event.keydown.enter")` this is not how you bind an event listener to a keyboard event. See https://stenciljs.com/docs/events#keyboard-events.

---

So, I think your component should look sth like this (simplified):

```js
@Component({ tag: 'otp-web-component' })
export class OtpWebComponent {
  @Prop() callback: () => void;

  goBack = () => {
    // ...
    this.callback();
  }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.goBack}>Click me</button>;
  }
}
```

and then you can use it like

```js
export default () => {
  const goTo = () => console.log('I got called');

  return <otp-web-component callback={goTo} />;
}
```

Comment: while passing function from index.html to stencil component should i pass it as string like <otp-component callback="">

Comment: You can't pass functions as props in HTML. You'll have to use JavaScript, e. g. `<otp-web-component></otp-web-component> <script>document.querySelector('otp-web-component').callback = myFunction;</script>`.

Comment: sorry for late reply the solution you provided is not working .

Comment: it throws an error callback is not a function and the way you showed me to code i have done as it is . if have not written any callback property in Index.html of stencil  component. thank you for your reply.

Comment: Ok it's probably because the code runs before the custom element has been defined... my example in the comment was just a snippet, not a fully working piece of html. you can try with sth like `<script>customElements.whenDefined('otp-web-component').then(() => { document.querySelector('otp-web-component').callback = myFunction; });</script>`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/whenDefined.